# set selected option in dropdownlist using yii1

Tags: php, yii

I am new in yii1 ,stuck with a problem.
   I need my dropdownlist to be selected based on the id passed from other page.

my controller

```
$cat = $_POST['mySelect'];
$post = file_get_contents("...................");   
$category = CJSON::decode($post, true);
$this->render('//Product/index', array('category'=>$category,'cat'=>$cat));
```

View page

```
<?php

echo CHtml::label('Category : ','cat'); 
                        $options = array();
                            foreach($category as $user) :

                                foreach($user as $use):

                                    $options[$use['id']] = $use['name'];
                                    if($options[$use['id']]== $cat){
                                        $sel='selected';
                                    }
                                endforeach;
                            endforeach;

                            echo CHtml::dropDownList('mySelect', 'name', $options,array('class'=>'selectpicker select_box','selected'=>$sel,'onchange'=>'select_bl(this.value)'));

?>
```

I don't have database.

i don't know how to use

```
 echo CHtml::dropDownList($cat, 'category',Html::listData(category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'),$classification_levels_options);
```

can any one help me with this???

In my code $cat is the id of the selected category's id, and $category is the list of all category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi look the syntax of `CHtml::dropDownList` is this

```
dropDownList($name,$select,$data,$htmlOptions=array())
```

so your `syntax` should be

```
<?php
 foreach($category as $user){
                                foreach($user as $use){

                                    $options[$use['id']] = $use['name'];
                                                                   }
                         }
    echo CHtml::dropDownList('category',$cat, $options);
```

I am assumning(from your question) that  `$options` is a `array` of `category` which you have get and `$cat` is a `key` value of any `category`

Normally we use CHtml::listdata to get array

if you have a model of `categories` `table` lets say name of `model` is `Category.php` then you can simple use `findall` and the `CHtml::list` data to get a `array`

```
$options = CHtml::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'));
```

then simply use // no need to use foreach loop

```
echo CHtml::dropDownList('category',$cat, $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

// $cat= your category id to be selected

echo CHtml::dropDownList('category',$cat,Html::listData(category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'));

Comment: shows error " include(category.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory "

Comment: in your query check your model name is correct Category::model()->findAll()

Comment: i don't have model class.

Comment: echo CHtml::dropDownList('category',$cat,Html::listData(Category::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name')); use this